# SQL Connection problems using MVC4 and EF 5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

We have developed a solution .NET Framwork 4.5 and ASP.NET MVC 4 that uses a SQL Server 2012 as a database. We encountered no problems on our dev machines but on the staging server we get the message `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`. This error occurs mostly when the application pool has been resetted. After some page reloads it usually works for some time.

Our network and server admins have looked into this and found everything being fine. Instead they found posts on the internet stating similar problems do occur because of .NET framework 4.5. Now I'm stuck in the middle. I tried connecting using IP, name, FQDN, explicitly enabling MARS and explicitly disabling async queries.

Comment: simplify the problem, create a simple test app to connect to the SQL server and run it from the same machine.  You can then at least eliminate MVC and EF from the problem, as that is unlikely to be it.  Sounds more like SQL config or network issue to me (i know, they always say everything is fine though until proven otherwise).  Are the number of connections to SQL server limited in its configuration?

Comment: Also could be the application using MVC/EF, are you opening a lot of connections to SQL and not closing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After heavy research and a lot of luck we found it to be a 'hardware' problem. The machines are virtualized and with a different virtual network adapter the problem has been (as it seems right now) resolved.